# Efficiently Building Summed Area Table

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing, sse

I am trying to construct a summed area table for later use in an adaptive thresholding routine. Since this code is going to be used in time critical software, I am trying to squeeze as many cycles as possible out of it.

For performance, the table is unsigned integers for every pixel.

When I attach my profiler, I am showing that my largest performance bottleneck occurs when performing the x-pass.

The simple math expression for the computation is:

```
sat_[y * width + x] = sat_[y * width + x - 1] + buff_[y * width + x]
where the running sum resets at every new y position.
```

In this case, `sat_` is a 1-D pointer of unsigned integers representing the SAT, and `buff_` is an 8-bit unsigned monochrome buffer.

My implementation looks like the following:

```
uint *pSat = sat_;
char *pBuff = buff_;

for (size_t y = 0; y < height; ++y, pSat += width, pBuff += width)
{
    uint curr = 0;
    for (uint x = 0; x < width; x += 4)
    {
        pSat[x + 0] = curr += pBuff[x + 0];
        pSat[x + 1] = curr += pBuff[x + 1];
        pSat[x + 2] = curr += pBuff[x + 2];
        pSat[x + 3] = curr += pBuff[x + 3];
    }
}
```

The loop is unrolled manually because my compiler (VC11) didn't do it for me. The problem I have is that the entire segmentation routine is spending an extraordinary amount of time just running through that loop, and I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts on what might speed it up. I have access to all of the SSE's sets, and AVX for any machine this routine will run on, so if there is something there, that would be extremely useful.

Also, once I squeeze out the last cycles, I then plan on extending this to multi-core, but I want to get the single thread computation as tight as possible before I make the model more complex.

Comment: Your code does not implement what you wrote in your first expression...  Specifically, you reset `curr` at the beginning of every row, but that's not implied by the expression.

Comment: You are right, I was playing fast and loose with the math. If you have a suggestion on how to re-write the math for the x pass, I am game. The implementation of the algorithm is correct, however, just not as fast as I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: Ok.  The reason I ask is because it's kind of critical as to whether this code could ever be vectorised/parallelised.  It sounds like you're in luck, as resetting on each row breaks the dependency chain.

Comment: Yeah, it feels like I should be able to vectorize it, I just can't figure out the right calls, since I would essentially want y0..3 to be the vector, but sse gather isn't implemented until AVX2

Comment: How large are your images, and if they are substantially larger than cache then how do your timings compare with your memory bandwidth?  For simple image processing operations it's often the case that the CPU isn't the bottleneck.

Comment: The images are fairly large, up to 6000x6000. I am pretty sure it is a bandwidth problem, though I would have expected so see a large hit on the first computation, and small hits on the 2-4th since the memory should already be loaded, but the profiler says all 4 occupy similar amounts of time.

Comment: Maybe I need to break apart my code a little bit more to see if the hit is from the load or the store.

Comment: What memory do you expect to be loaded after the first computation?  Because your data is larger than cache it seems like it will always stream from RAM.  I think it's going to be difficult to get much better performance than you have now.  Even strategic prefetches may not help because the processor is likely already doing it.

Comment: I tried prefetches but the compiler did a better job at it :/ I truly hope I can do better, but I may just have to resort to parallel. This alg should play well with hyperthreading

Comment: Parallel won't help if it uses the same saturated memory bandwidth.

Comment: Splitting a large memcpy into 2 chunks on different threads added a perf gain of 1.9x, so there is a hidden variable somewhere that I am missing. memcpy would be the ultimate bandwidth limited algorithm.

Comment: @rhashimoto Going parallel helped, just more marginally than I had hoped. Just moving the x pass to 2 threads reduced processing time by ~2ms, so I was pretty close to the bandwidth ceiling already.

Answer (score 2):

You have a dependency chain running along each row; each result depends on the previous one.  So you cannot vectorise/parallelise in that direction.

But, it sounds like each row is independent of all the others, so you can vectorise/paralellise by computing multiple rows simultaneously.  You'd need to transpose your arrays, in order to allow the vector instructions to access neighbouring elements in memory.<sup>*</sup>

However, that creates a problem.  Walking along rows would now be absolutely terrible from a cache point of view (every iteration would be a cache miss).  The way to solve this is to interchange the loop order.

Note, though, that each element is read precisely once.  And you're doing very little computation per element.  So you'll basically be limited by main-memory bandwidth well before you hit 100% CPU usage.

---

<sub>* This restriction may be lifted in AVX2, I'm not sure...</sub>

Comment: Interesting, so it would make it possible to vectorize at the expense of having to run a transpose.

Comment: For an SSE implementation, rather than transpose the entire image you might want to consider working with 16x16 tiles. You can do a fast 16x16 transpose which will be mainly register-based and then iterate through the 16 resulting vectors accumulating 16 partial sums.

Comment: @PaulR I tried that, and it was an interesting approach. It ended up being ~1ms slower per test image on average, unfortunately. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: OK - was that using a fast SSE register-based transpose ?

Comment: I was using the "_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS" macro combined with "_mm_castsi128_ps" because there isn't a version for 4 integers. MSDN says that the cast is a no-op. Is there a different transpose that you were thinking about?

Answer (score 1):

Algorithmically, I don't think there is anything you can do to optimize this further. Even though you didn't use the term OLAP cube in your description, you are basically just building an OLAP cube. The code you have is the standard approach to building an OLAP cube.

If you give details about the hardware you're working with, there might be some optimizations available. For example, there is a GPU programming approach that may or may not be faster. Note: Another post on this thread mentioned that parallelization is not possible. This isn't necessarily true... Your algorithm can't be implemented in parallel, but there are algorithms that maintain data-level parallelism, which could be exploited with a GPU approach.

Comment: I can make the algorithm parallel by simpling handing the first half of rows to thread A, and the other half to thread B for the X pass. When I implemented this, I got a small gain in per-frame perf, which led me to believe that I wasn't 100% bandwidth limited, just mostly. I have seen the GPU approach that uses recursive doubling, but I found that the overhead to moving data back and forth was my limiting factor.