# Summed area table in GLSL and GPU fragment shader execution

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, gpu

I am trying to compute the integral image (aka summed area table) of a texture I have in the GPU memory (a camera capture), the goal being to compute the adaptive threshold of said image. I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0, and still learning :).

I did a test with a simple gaussian blur shader (vertical/horizontal pass), which is working fine, but I need a way bigger variable average area for it to give satisfactory results.

I did implement a version of that algorithm on CPU before, but I'm a bit confused on how to implement that on a GPU.
I tried to do a (completely incorrect) test with just something like this for every fragment :

```
#version 100
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require

precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D           u_Texture;      // The input texture.
varying lowp vec2           v_TexCoordinate;    // Interpolated texture     coordinate per fragment.
uniform vec2                u_PixelDelta;           // Pixel delta

void main()
{
    // get neighboring pixels values
    float center = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).r;
    float a = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate + vec2(u_PixelDelta.x * -1.0, 0.0)).r;
    float b = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate + vec2(0.0, u_PixelDelta.y * 1.0)).r;
    float c = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate + vec2(u_PixelDelta.x * -1.0, u_PixelDelta.y * 1.0)).r;

    // compute value
    float pixValue = center + a + b - c;


    // Result stores value (R) and original gray value (G)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(pixValue, center, center, 1.0);
}
```

And then another shader to get the area that I want and then get the average. This is obviously wrong as there's multiple execution units operating at the same time.

I know that the common way of computing a prefix sum on a GPU is to do it in two pass (vertical/horizontal, as discussed here [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384316/glsl-integration-function/19384863#19384863) or [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259842/efficiently-building-summed-area-table)), but isn't there a problem here as there is a data dependency on each cell from the previous (top or left) one ?

I can't seem to understand the order in which the multiple execution units on a GPU will process the different fragments, and how a two-pass filter can solve that issue. As an example, if I have some values like this :

```
2 1 5
0 3 2
4 4 7
```

The two pass should give (first columns then rows):

```
2 1 5          2 3 8
2 4 7     ->   2 6 13
6 8 14         6 14 28
```

How can I be sure that, as an example, the value [0;2] will be computed as 6 (2 + 4) and not 4 (0 + 4, if the 0 hasn't been computed yet) ?

Also, as I understand that fragments are not pixels (If I'm not mistaken), would the values I store back in one of my texture in the first pass be the same in another pass if I use the exact same coordinates passed from the vertex shader, or will they be interpolated in some way ?

Comment: Which platform are you on? Given that the answer is going to be "probably not on the GPU" it may help to advise as to alternatives. E.g. iOS has the ability to offer CPU access to GPU textures (awkwardly), so you can incorporate a CPU step into your GL flow subject to glFinish-style synchronisation costs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tommy and Bartvbl address your questions about a summed-area table, but your core problem of an adaptive threshold may not need that.

As part of my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2) framework, I've done some experimentation with [optimizing blurs over large radii](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2013/10/21/optimizing-gaussian-blurs-mobile-gpu) using OpenGL ES. Generally, increasing blur radii leads to a significant increase in texture sampling and calculations per pixel, with an accompanying slowdown.

However, I found that for most blur operations you can apply a surprisingly effective optimization to cap the number of blur samples. If you downsample the image before blurring, blur at a smaller pixel radius (radius / downsampling factor), and then linearly upsample, you can arrive at a blurred image that is the equivalent of one blurred at a much larger pixel radius. In my tests, these downsampled, blurred, and then upsampled images look almost identical to the ones blurred based on the original image resolution. In fact, precision limits can lead to larger-radii blurs done at a native resolution breaking down in image quality past a certain size, where the downsampled ones maintain the proper image quality.

By adjusting the downsampling factor to keep the downsampled blur radius constant, you can achieve near constant-time blurring speeds in the face of increasing blur radii. For a adaptive threshold, the image quality should be good enough to use for your comparisons.

I use this approach in the Gaussian and box blurs within the latest version of the above-linked framework, so if you're running on Mac, iOS, or Linux, you can evaluate the results by trying out one of the sample applications. I have an adaptive threshold operation based on a box blur that uses this optimization, so you can see if the results there are what you want.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing ! I downsampled the image, rendered it into a texture, then I use that as a second texture in my adaptative threshold shader to pick the average at a given pixel (and the GPU will interpolate, which is nice). With some tweaking and averaging, it gives really nice results, and it's really fast ! I think I read your article before, it's a neat method ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

AS per the above, it's not going to be fantastic on a GPU. But assuming the cost of shunting data between the GPU and CPU is more troubling it may still be worth persevering.

The most obvious prima facie solution is to split horizontal/vertical as discussed. Use an additive blending mode, create a quad that draws the whole source image then e.g. for the horizontal step on a bitmap of width `n` issue a call that requests the quad be drawn `n` times, the 0th time at `x = 0`, the mth time at `x = m`. Then ping pong via an FBO, switching the target of buffer of the horizontal draw into the source texture for the vertical.

Memory accesses are probably O(n^2) (i.e. you'll probably cache quite well, but that's hardly a complete relief) so it's a fairly poor solution. You could improve it by divide and conquer by doing the same thing in bands — e.g. for the vertical step, independently sum individual rows of 8, after which the error in every row below the final is the failure to include whatever the sums are on that row. So perform a second pass to propagate those.

However an issue with accumulating in the frame buffer is clamping to avoid overflow — if you're expecting a value greater than 255 anywhere in the integral image then you're out of luck because the additive blending will clamp and `GL_RG32I` et al don't reach ES prior to 3.0.

The best solution I can think of to that, without using any vendor-specific extensions, is to split up the bits of your source image and combine channels after the fact. Supposing your source image were 4 bit and your image less than 256 pixels in both directions, you'd put one bit each in the R, G, B and A channels, perform the normal additive step, then run a quick recombine shader as `value = A + (B*2) + (G*4) + (R*8)`. If your texture is larger or smaller in size or bit depth then scale up or down accordingly.

(platform specific observation: if you're on iOS then you've hopefully already got a `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` in the loop, which means you have CPU and GPU access to the same texture store, so you might well prefer to kick this step off to GCD. iOS is amongst the platforms supporting `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch`; if you have access to that then you can write any old blend function you like and at least ditch the combination step. Also you're guaranteed that preceding geometry has completed before you draw so if each strip writes its totals where it should and also to the line below then you can perform the ideal two-pixel-strips solution with no intermediate buffers or state changes)

Comment: I'm using Android, but it's nice to know that there's a way to access texture data directly on iOS ! My image resolution is 1280x1024 (so costly to transfer from GPU to CPU side, downsampling could help as I only need a big 32x32 to 128x128 average). It's a jpeg coming from a camera via USB, decoded via MediaCodec (openmax), and updated to the GPU via a SurfaceTexture. I only have the original jpeg image cpu-side.

You're right about the problem with clamping in the fragment shader, I didn't though about that ! gl_FragColor is a lowp float vec4, so up to 1.0 max.

Comment: Possibly irrelevant, aside comment: I don't know what MediaCodec supports but a 128x128 average of a 1280x1024 JPEG should be obtainable without decoding the JPEG — if memory serves then JPEGs divide the image into 8x8 quadrants and perform the frequency domain stuff separately on each. So you could just take the 0Hz component from each bin and ignore the higher frequency parts to get an image scaled down by a factor of 8x8. i.e. I believe JPEG files effectively contain their own thumbnails, no DCT processing required. You know, should MediaCodec not already exploit that and it be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What you attempt to do cannot be done in a fragment shader. GPU's are by nature very different to CPU's by executing their instructions in parallel, in massive numbers at the same time. Because of this, OpenGL does not make any guarantees about execution order, because the hardware physically doesn't allow it to.

So there is not really any defined order other than "whatever the GPU thread block scheduler decides".

Fragments are pixels, sorta-kinda. They are pixels that potentially end up on screen. If another triangle ends up in front of another, the previous calculated colour value is discarded. This happens regardless of whatever colour was stored at that pixel in the colour buffer previously.

As for creating the summed area table on the GPU, I think you may first want to look at GLSL "Compute Shaders", which are specifically made for this sort of thing.

I think you may be able to get this to work by creating a single thread for each row of pixels in the table, then have every thread "lag behind" by 1 pixel compared to the previous row.

In pseudocode:

```
int row_id = thread_id()
for column_index in (image.cols + image.rows):
    int my_current_column_id = column_index - row_id
    if my_current_column_id >= 0 and my_current_column_id < image.width:
        // calculate sums
```

The catch of this method is that all threads should be guaranteed to execute their instructions simultaneously without getting ahead of one another. This is guaranteed in CUDA, but I'm not sure whether it is in OpenGL compute shaders. It may be a starting point for you, though.

Comment: Ha, yes, that's what I feared. I'd like to use compute shaders, but they're not part of OpenGL ES 2.0. That would have been convenient.

[That presentation](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/GDC2005_SATEnvironmentReflections.pdf) from ATI seems to demonstrate a way to compute a SAT on GPU using a vertex and pixel shader only, I'm trying to understand how they did that right now.

I could also maybe downscale it and compute it CPU-side, but the cost of doing that may be a bit high.

Answer (score 2):

It may look surprising for the beginner but the prefix sum or SAT calculation is suitable for parallelization. As the [Hensley](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqq-Da-fHVAhXFbRQKHbb4AmQQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.90.8836%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNEo4X8nAWdNpqHAdy0fviFA_9BDUA) algorithm is the most intuitive to understand (also implemented in OpenGL), more work-efficient parallel methods are available, see [CUDA scan](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html). The paper from [Sengupta](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=12201308707241435113&hl=pl&as_sdt=0,5&sciodt=0,5) discuss parallel method which seems state-of-the-art efficient method with reduce and down swap phases. These are valuable materials but they do not enter OpenGL shader implementations in detail. The closest document is the [presentation](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/GDC2005_SATEnvironmentReflections.pdf) you have found (it refers to [Hensley](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqq-Da-fHVAhXFbRQKHbb4AmQQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.90.8836%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNEo4X8nAWdNpqHAdy0fviFA_9BDUA) publication), since it has some shader snippets. This is the job which is doable entirely in fragment shader with FBO Ping-Pong. Note that the FBO and its texture need to have internal format set to high precision - GL_RGB32F would be best but I am not sure if it is supported in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: It's indeed possible, like you explained. I feel like the method from Sengupta may not work so well on GLES due to the fact that there is branching ? GL_RGB32F would probably be possible with the extension "OES_texture_float" ?
The trick I ended up implementing uses a downscaled and then linearly upsampled texture is perfect if you don't need to get the average value of an area of variable size, only a fixed one, and requires only two passes (downscale / upscale)